# Router during high traffic usage loses internet connectivity

Tags: wireless-networking, router, connection

I have a ASUS N56U connected to my modem. My direct connection to the modem works fine but my wifi seems to suffer from disconnections when I'm on skype or playing League of Legends. The disconnection doesn't disconnect my connection with the router, as windows doesn't actually say that there is anything wrong. Sometimes, when I wait a few seconds my connection comes back. Othertimes I reboot the router.

My internet is 60Mbps, and my router is set to default settings with DHCP. I'm not really sure what could be causing this issue. Previously I had another router that suffered similar issues. But as my modem seems to always be fine I have to blame the router. Is there some sort of configuration that I can set in my router?
I've tried the latest firmware and even this custom firmware:
https://code.google.com/p/rt-n56u/

they all have the issue

any one have ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you connect to the modem via PPPoE, or is it a cable modem?